# Spring: refering the resources/static folder

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing a Rest API using Spring Boot and AngularJS in the client side, i am uploading files to /resources/static/upload with Spring using the RestController below and using them in the client side

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class FilmController {
    @Autowired
    private FilmRepository filmRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/films", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveFilm(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {

        File convFile = new File("src/main/resources/static/upload/"+file.getOriginalFilename());

        convFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        Blob blob = new SerialBlob(file.getBytes());

        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        System.out.println(convFile.getName());


        filmRepository.save(new Film(convFile.getName(), blob));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/films", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Film> getAllFilms() {
        return filmRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Here is how i accessed the uploaded image "image.jpg"

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/upload/image.jpg" />
```

But, when i ran mvn package and i launch my application jar file, i can't access the uploaded image in the client side, i get 404 not found.

Can someone explain how Spring store and refer to static resources and how can i resolve this problem.

Comment: You cannot... You cannot upload to a path in the classpath which effectively will be inside the jar.

Comment: So where can i upload my files and still can access them in the client side?

Comment: Use a path on the file system or a suitable data storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using absolute path to the directory and this works in both cases: when it's runing with `mvn spring-boot:run` and when it's running as `java -jar app.jar`.

For example, you could try to save uploads to `/opt/upload` (make sure that it exists and user has permissions to write into it):

```
File convFile = new File("/opt/upload/"+file.getOriginalFilename());
```

Also you should configure Spring to serve uploads from this directory:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/upload/**")
          .addResourceLocations("file:/opt/upload/");
    }

}
```

More info about configuring resource handler: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources

Comment: How can access files in /opt/upload from the client side (angularjs)?

Comment: What do you mean by "accessing"? Images will be available as before, by URL like `http://localhost:8080/upload/image.jpg`

Comment: Nice, it worked! Only changes I had to make for angular is : For angular use `registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/upload/**").addResourceLocations("file:/opt/upload/");` along with `<img src="assets/upload/image.jpg">` , It worked both on port 8080 as well as 4200

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot store in the folder structure you see in your IDE that is not how your code will be in a deployed package

```
File convFile = new File("src/main/resources/static/upload/"+file.getOriginalFilename());
```

store using relative path

```
File convFile = new File("/static/upload/"+file.getOriginalFilename());
```

and also add the resource location mapping in spring config for your image upload folder .

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/upload/**" location="/static/upload/" />
```