# Spring Boot File upload location

Tags: spring-boot

I'm currently trying to grasp the concept in this [File upload tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) in Spring Boot especially the StorageProperties.

I'm wondering: where will the uploaded files go? I searched the
resources folder and static but no file are being uploaded there.

Comment: It depends on you where you want to store your file. In given link you have to implement StorageService interface and write your logic to store file in void store(MultipartFile file); method.

Comment: I know about the StorageService and its implementation.. I want to know about the value inside the StorageProperties Configuration, i don't know what directory the files are being uploaded and im wondering how would i set it up so that it will be save in the static folder.

Comment: so i did try to understand the code in the implementation of the StorageService and i found that the Path.resolve point to upload-dir\filename and the folder is put at the Project root folder outside the source. I know this already solve my question but how do i set the storage property to save uploaded files to the application resource folder.

Comment: Please provide code sample what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

The `StorageService` is just an interface. You have to provide its implementation.

Checkout this Github Repo,  [Sample App](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files/tree/master/complete)

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question and the answer is you cannot upload a file that will be effectively inside a Jar.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36769132/4748775

Im sorry for such question. hopefully this may help other beginners looking for a way 
to upload inside the project structure.